# Checking to see if a div with a certain class contains text or is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to check in jQuery if an element with a certain class contains some text. If it doesn't contain any text, then I want to remove the class.

```html
<div class="description">


</div>
```

Comment: So by "some text" you mean "something other than whitespace"?

Comment: @TylerH It is. Browser creates a `textNode` object for it.

Comment: @Vohuman Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: P.S. What if the element contains other elements, but none of them have text either? E.g., is `<div class="description">   <span>  </span>  </div>` considered "empty" for your purposes?

Comment: If none of the answers helped or you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**:empty**](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

```
$('.description:empty').removeClass('description');
```

According to documentation

> Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

```js
console.log($('.description:empty').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description"></div>
```

**However**, if there is poorly formed HTML as in the question(unnecessary whitespace), you will have to take a more manual approach

```
if ($(this).children().length == 0 && $(this).text().trim() == '')
```

```js
$('.description').each(function() {
  if ($(this).children().length == 0 && $(this).text().trim() == '') {
    console.log('entered');
    $(this).removeClass('description');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">


</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't the example shown in the question have a text node? There is whitespace shown...

Comment: It doesn't select the posted element. It contains textNodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$('.description').text().length)
    $('.description').hide();
```

Comment: Going on the example in the question, I think the OP probably wants to ignore white space.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.description').text().trim()=="") {
    $(this).hide();
else {
    /*non-empty actions */
}
```

Comment: Going on the example in the question, I think the OP probably wants to ignore white space.

Comment: You're right, I was already editing that when I read your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntex

```
if($('.description').innrHTML=='')
{
 $('.description').hide()
}
```

Comment: jQuery objects don't have an `.innerHTML` property. Also, the example shown in the question has some whitespace in the element.